# Change pop up position in folium

Tags: python, openstreetmap, folium

Hey so whenver I click on the markers on the folium map the pop up kind of takes up a lot of space. Sure I can change the hieght and the width but I want the pop up to appear on the right corner of my map or something like that.

Does anyone know how to change the position/alignment of a popup in folium?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to set only the popup to a different location, since the structure adds the popup to the latitude and longitude location. You can move the marker itself by adding the following setting. `folium.Marker([30, -100], popup=popup,draggable=True).add_to(m)`